# How to merge multiple simplecov directories inside CircleCI when running parallel_test?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, parallel-testing, circleci, simplecov

I have a rails application that runs parallel_test with rspec inside circleci

Looking around on Internet I added up this to the very beginnging of my `spec_helper.rb` file:

```
if ENV['COVERAGE']
  require 'simplecov'
  # on circleci change the output dir to the artifacts
  if ENV['CIRCLE_ARTIFACTS']
    dir = File.join("..", "..", "..", ENV['CIRCLE_ARTIFACTS'], "coverage")
    SimpleCov.coverage_dir(dir)
    SimpleCov.merge_timeout 3600
    SimpleCov.command_name "rspec_#{Process.pid.to_s}#{ENV['TEST_ENV_NUMBER']}"
  end
  SimpleCov.start 'rails'
end
```

The problem is that as a result I get different folders one for each circleci instance:

[image]

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: no one that works at circle-ci ?

Comment: Unrelated, but what does your circle.yml look like? I can't get this workign @fabrizioM

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I work at CircleCI. Unfortunately this isn't going to work - we don't collect the artifacts directories from different builds until after all builds have finished running, so tools that try to merge them together during the build won't work. We have talked about adding capabilities to do this, but it's not currently on our feature roadmap, sorry!

Comment: Is this still the case?  I am just about to implement @frank-c-eckert's solution via scp...

Answer (score 3):

For anyone who still looking for a solution to this problem, there is a new possibility: using ssh between containers to manually sync and merge reports, see the [docs](https://circleci.com/docs/ssh-between-build-containers). This is, however, not a turnkey solution, you will have to write the necessary scripts yourself.

Otherwise, you can also use an external coverage service (we use <strike>[coveralls](http://coveralls.io)</strike> [codecov](https://codecov.io)) together with CircleCI's [notification webhook](https://circleci.com/docs/configuration#notify).

**Edit**

You can add the webhook like this in your circle.yml (thanks Ian):

`notify:
  webhooks:
    - url: https://coveralls.io/webhook?repo_token=(your repo token)`

Comment: can you give a little more detail in how you configure coveralls to work with circle's webhooks?

Comment: Found this info at https://coveralls.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/203484329-Parallel-Build-Webhook

Answer (score 1):

To expound upon what Frank Eckert said, [Coveralls can do this](https://coveralls.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/203484329).  However, that documentation is slightly off.

Add to you `Gemfile`:

```
gem 'coveralls', require: false
```

Add to your `spec/spec_helper.rb`:

```
if ENV['CIRCLECI']
  # If running in CircleCI, run with Coveralls too
  require 'coveralls'
  Coveralls.wear!('rails')
end
```

Add to your `circle.yml` (not `coveralls.yml` as the article states):

```
notify:
  webhooks:
    - url: https://coveralls.io/webhook?repo_token=your-repo-token
```

Add to (or create) a `.coveralls.yml` in the root folder, and add:

```
repo_token: your-repo-token
```

Finally, go into the CircleCI project configuration and add an environment variable:  `COVERALLS_PARALLEL=true`

This worked for us, however we find errors in the proper line count ([reported to Coveralls](https://github.com/lemurheavy/coveralls-public/issues/696)) but it is working and gives us a good idea about our coverage changing over time.